# Problem installing scikit-image on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, scikit-image

I'm trying to install sci-kit image on my raspberry pi, but I'm running into some problems. Previously it was giving me the error that the file 'libaec.h' was missing. I installed libaec using pip, and then that error was solved. However, now it is giving me the error that 'blosc.h' is missing. I managed to install blosc with pip but the error is still there (only showing the last part of the error message):

```
   building 'imagecodecs._blosc' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Iimagecodecs -I/usr/include/python3.7m -I/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -c imagecodecs/_blosc.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.7/imagecodecs/_blosc.o
    In file included from /usr/include/python3.7m/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822,
                     from /usr/include/python3.7m/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                     from /usr/include/python3.7m/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from imagecodecs/_blosc.c:598:
    /usr/include/python3.7m/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
      ^~~~~~~
    imagecodecs/_blosc.c:602:10: fatal error: blosc.h: No such file or directory
     #include "blosc.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-txmkharf/imagecodecs/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-1ugl_qdj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-txmkharf/imagecodecs/
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install blosc
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: blosc in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.9.1)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Is blosc located in the right place? If not, how can I move it to the correct place?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem when installing a package that depends on imagecodecs. I was able to solve it by updating pip from version 18 to version 20 using

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Upgrading pip worked for an issue encountered while installing imagecodes on Centos 7

Answer (score 1):

I believe that imagecodecs does *not* used the installed blosc but instead uses its own version, which is why installing blosc wouldn't help. If you look at the [imagecodecs page on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/2019.11.5/), you can find this help information:

> To install the requirements for building imagecodecs from source code on current Debian based Linux distributions, run:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev cython3 python3-setuptools python3-pip python3-wheel python3-numpy libz-dev libblosc-dev liblzma-dev liblz4-dev libzstd-dev libpng-dev libwebp-dev libbz2-dev libopenjp2-7-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libjxr-dev liblcms2-dev libtiff-dev`

On the other hand, they also say:

> The imagecodecs package can be challenging to build from source code.

Fingers crossed that those instructions work for you!

Comment: The latest version requires other libraries, check them out at https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/. The link in this answear is for a specific old version.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm. There might've been a mixup in packages. Try uninstalling blosc, and then re-installing. If the problem still persists, then try uninstalling and reinstalling all the packages you installed. The only thing I can think if after that is to use a package installer such as anaconda. Sometimes, it can perform miracles! I hope this helps you.